# Regex in Express.js router

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

I'm trying to find some documentation about regex in Express, but the information in Express API is very sparse. I'm trying to do a regex matching objectID. This example about regex is given in the Express documentation.

```
router.get(/^\/commits\/(\w+)(?:\.\.(\w+))?$/, function(req, res){ ... });
```

I have tried the following in my router, and it *seems* to work fine.

```
client.get('/staff/:id([0-9a-fA-F]{24})', function(req, res) { ... });
```

But there are some differences that i can't figure out...

- My example is surrounded in `'`, the example in the API is not. What
  does this mean? Is my expression a string and not a regex?
- I dont use: `/^` or `?$/`. Not knowing much about
  regex I guess this is some kind of anchors. Do i need this?
- I dont escape `\` the first part of my URL `/staff/:id`. Is this something i
  should do?

Also, does anyone know about a *extensive* resource for reading about regex in Express routers... or parameter options or whatever it is I'm doing above...

Comment: Please remove the check mark, since I think my answer is wrong about the string part. It seems that express.js has different way of processing when string is passed in.

Comment: Yes, I have realised this aswell. Still you gave me lots of good info about the regex parts =)

Comment: The `:id` part needs to be defined with `param`

Answer (score 1):

It is worth reading the source code for the route matching, but here is the short form.

- `'abc'` is a JS string; `/abc/` is a JS regex. The string can be used to create a regex, which is what you are doing. So both are valid. To see the difference, try doing `var re = /abc/` and `var re = new RegExp('abc')`
- `^` is a starting anchor while `$` is an ending anchor. `^abc` will match "abc", "abcde" but not "zabcd" because it needs to **start** with "abc". `abc$` will match "abc", "zabc" but not "abcd", because it needs to end with "abc".
- when you use an actual RegExp expression starting with `/` and ending with `/`, if you want to use slashes in your RegExp, you need to escape them, else how will the interpreter know that this is a slash character and not the end of your RegExp? If you are using a string, it knows it is not, and so you do not need to escape.

For the last, try this:

```
"abc".match(/abc/);  // works
"abc".match('/abc/');  // fails because there are no slashes
"/abc/".match('/abc/');  // works
"/abc/".match(/abc/);  // works because "abc" is in there
```

Of course, you *can* escape the slashes, if you so choose

```
"/abc/".match('\/abc\/');  // works
"abc".match('\/abc\/');  // fails
```